# How to get and pass value from GridView to Method being called by DropDownList in GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following `GridView` containing a `DropDownList` which calls a method based on `SelectedValue`:

On the row where the selection is being made, how do I get the `Customer ID` from the `GridView` and pass it as an argument to the Method being called below?

*Code:*

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdLoadData" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server">

<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Example">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlExampleDropDownList"  runat="server" 
     AutoPostBack="true" Width="100" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlExampleDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Text="---- Select --" Value="select" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Do Task A" Value="Task A" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Do Task B" Value="Task B" />
</asp:DropDownList> 
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:BoundField DataField="LAST_NAME" HeaderText="Last Name" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="FIRST_NAME" HeaderText="First Name" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="MiDDLE_NAME" HeaderText="Middle Name" />

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Customer ID">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblCustomerID" Text='<%#Eval("CUST_ID") %>' runat="server" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind:

```
    public string DoTaskA(string customerId)
    {
        return customerId;
    }

    public string DoTaskB(string customerId)
    {
        return customerId;
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadData();
        }  
    }

    protected void ddlExampleDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList dropDownList = (DropDownList)sender;
        GridViewRow gridViewRow = (GridViewRow)dropDownList.Parent.Parent;

         if(dropDownList.SelectedValue=="Task A")
         {
             //Pass Customer ID here
             DoTaskA();
         }
         else if(dropDownList.SelectedValue=="Task B")
         {
             //Pass Customer ID here
             DoTaskB();
         }
    }
```

Comment: So you want pass customer ID to the SelectedIndex_changed method?

Comment: Yes: When an value is selected, regardless of what value, I need to get the Customer ID for that row and pass it to the corresponding DoTask `method`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to add "CustID" as an attribute to your DropDownList Control like below:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlExampleDropDownList"  runat="server" 
 AutoPostBack="true" Width="100" CustID='<%#Eval("CUST_ID") %>'
OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlExampleDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged">
<asp:ListItem Text="---- Select --" Value="select" />
<asp:ListItem Text="Do Task A" Value="Task A" />
<asp:ListItem Text="Do Task B" Value="Task B" />
```

And get your CustomerID in your `SelectedIndexChanged` event should be like this:

```
protected void ddlExampleDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList dropDownList = (DropDownList)sender;
    GridViewRow gridViewRow = (GridViewRow)dropDownList.Parent.Parent;

    string lsCustomerID = Convert.ToString(dropDownList.Attributes["CustID"]);

     if(dropDownList.SelectedValue=="Task A")
     {
         //Pass Customer ID here
         DoTaskA(lsCustomerID);
     }
     else if(dropDownList.SelectedValue=="Task B")
     {
         //Pass Customer ID here
         DoTaskB(lsCustomerID);
     }
}
```

Comment: Wow!! This is awesome. There are other solutions for the same issue that span a who page of code: This is very minimal and perfect. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Another method without changing your markup will be,

```
Label myLabel = gridviewRow.FindControl("lblCustomerID") as Label;
string customerID = myLabel.Text;
```